# GeForce 9600GT support for dual monitor setup

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, splitter

I have a NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT (point of view, [link](http://www.xgcdb.com/cards/point-of-view/geforce-9600-gt-r-vga150961-1.html)) on an Asus M2V-MX motherboard. The card has one DVI, HDMI and S-Video output. The graphics card does not seem to support dual monitors: the driver control panel for the graphics card does not detect a second monitor that is attached via S-Video (which leads me to believe that it doesn't support dual monitors with DVI and the other connections).

Would it be possible to use a VGA/DVI splitter to attach two monitors to the single DVI output on the graphics card? Would this allow for a dual monitor setup, or only mirroring? How do I know if the graphic card supports this?

With this particular motherboard, would it be possible to use the onboard video for another monitor?

Comment: Did you try connecting one monitor to HDMI and one to DVI?

Comment: I tried S-Video once, but I think it wasn't plug and play, so it needed to be connected during computer start. But I didn't have the second screen that time so I cannot tell if there is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with S-Video is a very poor method of detecting if a card supports dual monitors, because the S-Video outputs are usually tacked on pretty poorly, and you can usually choose between either the S-Video or the VGA.

I've never seen a dual-head card that doesn't support dual monitors via the VGA and DVI connectors.

Comment: Since there is only one DVI output (no VGA), it's difficult to test dual monitors without using the S-Video.

Comment: @Theo - sorry, didn't realise that. My 9600GT had both heads, I didn't realise that there were ones with only one.

Answer (score 0):

Using a splitter *might* allow you to stretch the desktop across two monitors. What's the maximum resolution on the control panel? If it's something over 2400 pixels wide then you might be in luck.

As the card only has one output then it's unlikely that it will mirror the displays. This functionality is usually on dual output cards.

Comment: The card supports 2560x1600.Is there any way of knowing whether or not the card supports a splitter, without buying one?

Comment: @Theo - unless you find someone who's done it then there's not really any other way. With that resolution available it *might* work. Do you have a local store that'll be happy to take the splitter back if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood, I do not think it's possible to use a splitter unless you have a graphics card that supports it. Instead, I used the HDMI output to connect to a second monitor to extend my desktop.

Thank you for your fast responses.